# component diagram advice framework

Tags: architecture, frameworks, components, uml, diagram

I've been tasked with documenting our high-level software architecture that **uses** an in-house developed framework for robotics (similar to ROS.) I'll try and keep it simple.

In a component diagram, how do I represent that a component is instantiated by a class loader (based on its type specified in an XML file) in the base framework application provided and ran in a separate thread? The component implements and instantiates services provided by the framework (i.e network communications.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use an `<<instantiate>>` relation like in this example taken from the UML 2.5 specs on p. 39:

> In Figure 7.19, the CarFactory Class has a Dependency on the Car Class. In this case, the Dependency is a Usage with the standard stereotype «Instantiate» applied, indicating that an instance of the CarFactory Class creates instances of the Car Class.

[image]

Note that OMG uses some "artistic" arrow end (they are not as consistent in their documentation as they should be). A simple open triangle is used more commonly. On p. 39:

> A Dependency is shown as a dashed arrow between two model Elements. The model Element at the tail of the arrow (the client) depends on the model Element at the arrowhead (the supplier). The arrow may be labeled with an optional keyword or stereotype and an optional name...

The line they use resembles more a dotted than a dashed line, though.
Sigh.

Comment: Thanks, this is really clear! One other thing I can't figure out, from the end of my post: say the component (i.e. car) implements and instantiates services provided by the framework (i.e network communications), would I represent that as a required interface on car and have the framework component "realise" the interface (or vice versa) or would I skip representing/showing the interface on the component and instead just use the "realise" arrow?

Comment: Looking through the UML spec you mentioned (thanks), I see there is the answer in there p 171. "Figure 10.9 ISensor, a provided Interface of ProximitySensor, is shown as inherited by CapacitiveSensor".

Comment: You can use the lollipop notation and/or alternatively use a realize for a provided and dependency for a required interface (each to an `<<interface>> stereotype class). Should I add a picture or is that clear?